# sending pictures from Android to Matlab on PC

Tags: android, image, matlab, transfer

I want Matlab to perform as a server and Android Java app to perform as a client. Android should transfer a byte array of size 460K to Matlab.
I cannot manage to get the entire array correctly on Matlab.
The first call to fread in Matlab reads a random number of bytes (around 320K-290K) - this number is correctly presented by t.BytesAvailable.
After that t.BytesAvailable gets 0 and no further reading is possible.
Here is what I used:

Java client code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.0.2", 3000);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(buffer, 0, 460000);
out.flush();
out.close();
socket.close();
```

Matlab server code:

```
t=tcpip('0.0.0.0', 3000, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 500000); 
fopen(t); 
pause(1);
while (get(t, 'BytesAvailable') > 0) 
    display(get(t, 'BytesAvailable'));
    data=fread(t, t.BytesAvailable, 'uint8');
end
fclose(t); 
delete(t); 
clear t
```

Matlab version:

### >> ver

MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)

Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

### Java Version: Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode

MATLAB                                                Version 8.1        (R2013a)
Computer Vision System Toolbox                        Version 5.2        (R2013a)
Image Acquisition Toolbox                             Version 4.5        (R2013a)
Image Processing Toolbox                              Version 8.2        (R2013a)
Instrument Control Toolbox                            Version 3.3        (R2013a)
MATLAB Coder                                          Version 2.4        (R2013a)

Answer (score 1):

Sending a large amount of data over TCP and immediately closing the socket right after may be a little "unsafe". Check out this super informative guide - [SO_LINGER](http://ia600609.us.archive.org/22/items/TheUltimateSo_lingerPageOrWhyIsMyTcpNotReliable/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable.html) - and this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874021/close-socket-directly-after-send-unsafe) for a possible clean work around.

A simpler, dirtier, workaround in case you can afford it is simply to wait (with a `sleep` call) after sending and before `socket.close()`.