# winsock2: send() fails if socket is dead [not really]

Tags: tcp, send, winsock2

Calling send() on a TCP socket which has already been dropped by the client causes what appears to be a memory access violation, as when I run a server application I made and then bombard it with requests from a browser, it crashes after serving between about 7 and 11 requests. Specifically, it accepts the connections and then sits for up to 10 seconds or so, then Windows throws up the "This program has stopped working..." message. No such crash happens if I remove the send() calls, leading me to believe that Microsoft's send() does not safely handle a socket being closed from the other end.

I am aware there are various ways to check whether the socket has in fact been closed, but I don't want to check then send, because there's still a chance a client could cut out between checking and sending.

---

**Edit:** I noticed [close() socket directly after send(): unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874021/close-socket-directly-after-send-unsafe) in the "Similar Questions" box, and although it doesn't quite fit my situation, I am now wondering if calling close() quickly after send() could be the contributing to the problem.

If this is the case, a solution involving checking then closing *would* work as it does not have the implication stated above. However, I am unaware of how to check whether closesocket() would be safe.

---

**Edit:** I would also be fine with a way to detect that send() has in fact broken and prevent the entire application from crashing.

---

**Edit:** I thought I'd finally update this question, considering I figured out the issue a while ago and there may be curious people stumbling across this. As it turns out, the issue had nothing to do with the `send` function or anything else related to sockets. In fact, the problem was something incredibly stupid I was doing: calling `free` on invalid pointers (`NULL` and junk-data addresses alike). A couple of years ago I had finally updated my compiler from a very outdated version I was originally using, and I suppose the very outdated standard library implementation was what allowed me to get away with such a cringe-worthy practice, and it seems that what I saw as an issue with `send` was a side-effect of that.

Answer (score 2):

I have been programming in WinSock for over a decade, and have never seen or heard of `send()` throwing an exception on failure (in fact, no Win32 API function throws an exception on failure). If the socket is closed, an appropriate error code is reported.  So something else is going on in your code.  Maybe the pointer you pass to the `buf` parameter is not pointing at a valid memory block, or maybe if the value you pass to the `len` parameter is beyond the bounds of `buf`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look again at send()'s arguments and post if I find out what I was missed when trying to fix it before.

Answer (score 2):

Like @RemyLebeau, I have been programming in Winsock for over a decade, in my case well over *two* decades, and I have never seen this either.

Microsoft's `send()` handles sending to a connection that has already been closed by the other end,  by returning `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1) with `WSAGetLastError()` returning `WSAECONNRESET`.  Unless the connection was lost abnormally (network failure, etc), in which case WinSock does not know the connection is gone, and `send()` happily keeps buffering outbound data until the socket's buffer fills up, or the socket times out internally so failures are then reported.

The send/close question you refer to contains nothing about memory access errors, and in any case calling `close()` *after* `send()` can't possibly cause the prior `send()` to misbehave, unless you have managed to get time running backwards.

You have a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: It's been multiple years - not because it took me that long to figure it out (thank Christ) - but because I forgot I had asked this.

Comment: But as it turns out, you were right: the issue had absolutely nothing to do with sockets, and was instead a symptom of a really stupid thing I was doing, `free`ing invalid addresses.