# Does TCP close( ) ensure that all the data is delivered to the receiver

Tags: tcp, closesocket

I am implementing a simple proxy application in which I always receive data from one end and send to the other end.

In such a case, once I am sure that I am done with receiving all the data from the incoming leg, can I call directly `close( )` without calling `shutdown( )`? If I do so, will `close( )` ensure that all the data is delivered to the destination on the outgoing leg and received by the application at the destination?

Or in such a case, is it mandatory that I initiate a shutdown before I initiate a close?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874021/close-socket-directly-after-send-unsafe - close should make it so that data is delivered barring no major network problem.

Answer (score 0):

> can I call directly close() without calling shutdown()

You can. `shutdown` is only necessary if you would like to half-close the connection (i.e. read or write end).

> will the close( ) ensure that all the data is delivered to the destination on the outgoing leg and received by the application at the destination

`close` does in the background what a blocking `send` does, no more, no less. If that background `send` fails though, you will not get any error indication.

There is also `SO_LINGER` socket option you can tweak if necessary:

> ```
>   SO_LINGER
>          Sets or gets the SO_LINGER option.  The  argument  is  a  linger
>          structure.
>
>              struct linger {
>                  int l_onoff;    /* linger active */
>                  int l_linger;   /* how many seconds to linger for */
>              };
>
>          When  enabled,  a  close(2) or shutdown(2) will not return until
>          all queued messages for the socket have been  successfully  sent
>          or  the  linger  timeout  has been reached.  Otherwise, the call
>          returns immediately and the closing is done in  the  background.
>          When  the socket is closed as part of exit(2), it always lingers
>          in the background.
> ```

Comment: Small note on `shutdown()`. It will affect all copies of the socket such as those created with `dup()`, `dup2()` or `fork()`. The `close()` function affects only one copy of the socket. If it is not closing the last copy then the other copies of the socket continue to operate as normal.