# close() SSL socket directly after receive(): unsafe?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, race-condition

Is it wise/safe to close() a socket directly after the last receive()?

I am asking because I examined what happens on the sending side of the socket, and if I am using Java and TLS, the code there is

```
/**
 * Write the data out, NOW.
 */
@Override
public synchronized void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
        throws IOException {
    if (b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else if (off < 0 || len < 0 || len > b.length - off) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (len == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // check if the Socket is invalid (error or closed)
    socket.checkWrite();

    // Delegate the writing to the underlying socket.
    try {
        socket.writeRecord(b, off, len);
        socket.checkWrite();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // shutdown and rethrow (wrapped) exception as appropriate
        socket.handleException(e);
    }
}
```

from: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/26ac622a4cab/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/AppOutputStream.java#l68

This means, with the second call to `socket.checkWrite();`, Java checks that the socket is writable *after* the last chunk of data is sent. Race is then possible, where on the receiving side I close after I receive the last chunk, but before the sending side does its last check, and I end up with a `SocketException` being thrown on the sending side.

What I described in the paragraph above seems what is actually happening to me in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6956. The socket at the point of the second check is in state `cs_SENT_CLOSE = 5` and I get the `SocketException`.

Related to: [close() socket directly after send(): unsafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874021/close-socket-directly-after-send-unsafe)

Comment: I am not using these directly. These are just the underlying implementation for the normal `Socket` operations when using TLS.

Comment: It is wise and safe to close an SSLSocket after you are finished with it. I don't see how a race condition is possible.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Client code executes `socket.writeRecord(b, off, len);`, Server code receives that, realizes the data signal end of stream from client, and knowing that, server closes the socket. Some time passes, and now the client is executing the next line, `socket.checkWrite();` and the check now fails, because the socket is now in state `cs_SENT_CLOSE`. If the check line was executed few milliseconds sooner, then the check would've succeeded. Therefore a race.

Comment: That was a good description, and I'm not expert enough on sockets to address the underlying timing issues. However, in general, for SSL, both client *and* server need to have a shared, secure understanding of when the connection is closed. In your example, the client should know that it sent the final record and it should shutdown the write side of the connection, or simply close the socket.

Comment: I'm also looking at the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/security/ssl/SSLSocketImpl.java#SSLSocketImpl)